# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat, jersey

I'm creating a REST Api (Dynamic Web Project ) with the help of : Eclipse (EE-2020), Tomcat(9) and Jersey (2.31)... **(Without using Maven)**

I'm facing the following issue, and **unable to resolve it from last 48 hours.**

```
Jul 07, 2020 10:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [trying] as unavailable
Jul 07, 2020 10:08:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [trying] in web application [/First] threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:521)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1030)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4868)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
```

Please Help !!

Code below:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>First</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>trying</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
    
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>trying</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

**Hello.java**

```
package test;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
        
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String returnSomething()
    {
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

The Project Settings are as follows :

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWTKX.png)
2. 

[image]

Comment: You are mixing Jakarta EE9 jars (the M and RC jars) with Jakarta EE 8 jars (Jersey 2.31, Tomcat 9). They are not compatible.

Comment: So what should I do exactly ? @jan.supol

Comment: To start safe, grab the version of Jersey you want to use and check the dependencies which Jersey uses.

Comment: I've downgraded the version from 3.0.0-M2 to 2.26-b03...

Now I'm facing a totally different problem, and it is that:
I'm sending the object of a class back to client in XML format (used @XmlRootElement), but it is showing ERROR 500 in the browser and no logs in console. What is the probable cause of this?

Comment: 3.0.0-M2 is JAX-RS API, 2.26-b03 is a milestone release of Jersey (the JAX-RS implementation), which existed before the corresponding JAX-RS 2.1 API was final. You really are mixing things...